# Use vapply on a list of factors

Tags: r

I have a list of ordered factor vectors, and I want to find the lowest level in each element of the list. It's a simple exercise using `sapply`, but I am doing this inside a function, so would like to use `vapply` for safety. The trouble is, using `vapply` always returns an integer vector, and I can't figure out how to specify `FUN.VALUE` so that it returns a factor. Is there a way?

```
lvls <- ordered(letters)

fac1 <- factor(c("b", "a", "c"), levels = lvls, ordered = TRUE)
fac2 <- factor(c("f", "z", "m"), levels = lvls, ordered = TRUE)
fac3 <- factor(c("p", "d", "q"), levels = lvls, ordered = TRUE)

fac_list <- list(fac1, fac2, fac3)

sapply(fac_list, min) ## Works

## [1] a f d
## Levels: a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z

vapply(fac_list, min, FUN.VALUE = factor("a", levels = lvls))

## [1] 1 6 4
```

Comment: A bit of a runaround, but the `v` in `vapply` seems to suggest it can only be used to return a `vector`; `?vector` shows that a `vector` can only be declared for an "atomic mode", which the same page lists as one of `logical`, `integer`, `numeric`/`double`, `complex`, `character` and `raw`. It's not clear form `?vapply` that a `factor` is excluded from a "(generalized) vector", but I think the generalization means `array` types (since they're simply vectors with a defined dimension).

Comment: Long story short, it seems `vapply` won't be able to give you a `factor` directly; luckily for you, @bouncyball's solution below is perfectly fine.

Comment: I think you're right @MichaelChirico, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I would have preferred to offer this as a comment on your post)

If I understand correctly

```
lvls[vapply(fac_list, min, FUN.VALUE = factor('a',levels = lvls))]

> lvls[vapply(fac_list, min, FUN.VALUE = factor('a',levels = lvls))]
[1] a f d
Levels: a < b < c < d......
```

would be a 'hacky' solution to your problem.

Comment: No need to be humble, I think this is the correct approach given my understanding of the problem.

Comment: Thanks @bouncyball, this works fine and will have to do!  I think the comments on the original question are correct - vapply will only return a generalized vector, hence no factors.